# mixing asp.net webform and asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I had `webform project` now i add `MVC` to it. every thing work correct for `.aspx` pages, but not work for `.cshtml` file and it has following error:

```
The view 'hh' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/hh.aspx
~/Views/Home/hh.ascx
~/Views/Shared/hh.aspx
~/Views/Shared/hh.ascx
```

the project Not Search for `.cshtml` files. any idea for that?

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning - your MVC application is looking for `aspx` views (doesn't "have to" be razor views - aka vb/cs/html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that razor view engine is not registered on your application. In this case you need to register it somewhere in your Application_Start in Global.asax:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

You can verify if engine is registered by inspecting `ViewEngines.Engines` when running your application.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But it has following error: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'RazorViewEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Mahdi_Nine You need to have a reference to System.Web.Mvc.dll and `using System.Web.Mvc;` in the same file. Or you can use fully qualified path, like `ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine());`